# When do perl subs pass arguments as `$_` and when is it `$_[0]`?

Tags: perl, coderef

I noticed that the [Parallel::Loops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::Loops) module uses `$_` as the argument to its subref.  This question isn't about [Parallel::Loops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::Loops) per-se, it is about the coderef calling convention.

This is their example, note that `$_` is passed to the sub:

```perl
$pl->foreach( \@parameters, sub {
    # This sub "magically" executed in parallel forked child
    # processes
 
    # Lets just create a simple example, but this could be a
    # massive calculation that will be parallelized, so that
    # $maxProcs different processes are calculating sqrt
    # simultaneously for different values of $_ on different CPUs
    # (Do see 'Performance' / 'Properties of the loop body' below)
 
    $returnValues{$_} = sqrt($_);
});
```

...but I've always used `$_[0]` or `@_` for values passed to a sub:

```perl
$a = sub { print "\$_=$_\n" ; print "\$_[0]=$_[0]\n" };
$a->(1);

# prints out
# $_=
# $_[0]=1
```

Notice in my example `$_` didn't work, but `$_[0]` (ie, `@_`) does.  What is different between the coderef in [Parallel::Loops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::Loops)'s example, and the coderef in my example?

Note that their example isn't a typo: it only works if you use `$_`, which is why I'm posing this question.

Comment: you need to check the docs to see how to use particular module/subs. $_ is often used as fallback when no argument is given, but docs should be clear about it, like many core subs which explicitly state they'll use $_ value when no arguments are given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the module source when you want to know how it's doing its thing :)

In `Parallel::Loops::foreach`, the module sets `$_` before it calls the subroutine you provided. Since this is in a forked process, it doesn't do anything to protect the value of `$_`. Notice the various layers of code refs in that module.

```
# foreach is implemented via while above
sub foreach {
    my ($self, $varRef, $arrayRef, $sub);
    if (ref $_[1] eq 'ARRAY') {
        ($self, $arrayRef, $sub) = @_;
    } else {
        # Note that this second usage is not documented (and hence not
        # supported). It isn't really useful, but this is how to use it just in
        # case:
        #
        # my $foo;
        # my %returnValues = $pl->foreach( \$foo, [ 0..9 ], sub {
        #     $foo => sqrt($foo);
        # });
        ($self, $varRef, $arrayRef, $sub) = @_;
    }
    my $i = -1;
    $self->while( sub { ++$i <= $#{$arrayRef} }, sub {
        # Setup either $varRef or $_, if no such given before calling $sub->()
        if ($varRef) {
            $$varRef = $arrayRef->[$i];
        } else {
            $_ = $arrayRef->[$i];
        }
        $sub->();
    });
}
```

You could do that same thing. Every time you want to run your code ref, set the value of `$_` first:

```
for_all( [ qw(1 3 7) ], sub { print "$_\n" } );

sub for_all {
    my( $array, $sub ) = @_;

    foreach my $value ( @$array ) {
        local $_ = $value;
        $sub->();
        }
    }
```

Take a look at [Mojo::Collection](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Collection), for example, that does this with its code refs. [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) has several utilities that do this too.

Comment: Neat!  I didn't realize `$_` was super global.  Not that I use threads because they scare me in Perl, but is $_ at least scoped to a thread?

Comment: Since this comment seems related to my answer, I answered there.

Comment: But forked processes aren't threads. There are no threads here.

Answer (score 4):

> Notice in my example $_ didn't work

Because you never set `$_`, unlike the following snippets:

```perl
local $_ = 1;
$a->();
```

```perl
$a->() for 1;
```

Note that `$_` is a "super global", meaning `$_` refers to `$::_` aka `$main::_` no matter what the current namespace (as set by `package`) is. So this works even if the sub and the sub's callee are associated with different packages.

Comment: Re "*is `$_` at least scoped to a thread?*", Yes, each thread has its own Perl interpreter with its own variables. (When you create a new thread, you clone the existing interpreter, getting a copy of each variable in the parent interpreter.)

Answer (score -2):

`$_` and `$_[0]` are two different variables.

[`$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_) is called "The default input and pattern-searching space" in [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar), whereas`$_[0]` refers to the first element in the `@_` array. In Perl, the namespace is not shared between different variable types. I.e. `$var` has nothing to do with `$var_[0]` or `@var`.

[`@_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@_) is used inside a subroutine for the arguments passed to the subroutine. `$_` is not used by a subroutine (unless you specifically tell it to). However, in a lot of functions, `$_` is the default variable used, and that is what this module is trying to simulate. For example:

```
for (...) {      # aliases loop elements to $_
    print;       # prints $_
}
```

Now, I'm not 100% sure of all the implications of your example module code, but it seems to be assigning to `$_`. This could just be any variable name, such as `$foo`, but they chose `$_`.

I think one should avoid using `$_` in package subs, since it may contaminate `$_` as a global variable, leading to errors that are hard to diagnose.

Comment: I think Bork is close to right, and at least not wrong enough to DV.   His first answer post (before he edited) did say _"I'm not 100% sure of all the implications of your example module code, but it seems to be assigning to $\_"_ which is basically what the other answers pointed out.  This is the first time that I realized `$_` can be set by a caller and be picked up by the coderef being called subsequently; I always thought $_ was scoped to at least the sub and certainly the module...but clearly I had that wrong.  /upvote.

Comment: @briandfoy Well, you say that, but the OP also says that this question is *not* about this module, but about coderefs, and hence, not about forks. If someone does not know why a coderef that does not set $_ does not alter $_, then that is a hint that they are misunderstanding variables in subroutines. And in this case confusing $_[0] and $_. At least, that was my interpretation.

Comment: @Bork judging by your comments and your other answers, it seems likely (to me) that this isn't AI-generated. My initial reasoning: a well-written, fairly complete, but slightly off answer by a new account sounds a lot like AI (we've seen that countless time over the past year). Brian d Foy's answer is IMO more useful, but since OP commented that this answer was useful to him, maybe my interpretation of the question wasn't quite right. Anyways, apologies for the accusation; I've retracted my downvote, and I hope that you continue contributing to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Dada I understand your explanation and accept your apology. It was an interesting take on the Turing test. Soon we will all be redundant.